# How to represent parent-child data in R?

Tags: r, dataset

I want to import some data into R, and wonder how to structure it. I have used R before, but I am still at a very beginner level.

The data represents a typical one-to-many relationship, and is available as XML. To not make you wrap your heads around the complicated reality of my actual data, let's use the infamous Order -> OrderItem example. My XML file contains a collection of Orders, and each order contains, beside some simple-type elements, a collection of OrderItems, each order item having its own simple-type elements.

I guess I could either make two data frames, relational-style, one for orders and one for order items. Or I could try to make a data frame of orders and somehow box a mini data frame of order items into each. Or maybe try to define my own objects? I have never done any OO in R.

I assume that there is a "right" way to do it in R, and that its built-in tools make it easy to work with one of these three structures. But I don't know which one it is. Or is it a fourth approach I haven't even thought of? Which should I choose?

I already looked at documentation of packages for importing XML. They explained which methods to use to get at the data from certain nodes, but didn't do anything to answer my question. The examples always included flat data.

The data analysis will certainly include questions which need the relation of Orders and OrderItems. For example, something like "are there items which are more frequently ordered on a monday than on a sunday".

Here a minimal working example of the current state of the data:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<orders>
    <order>
        <orderDate>01.01.1850</orderDate>
        <customerName>Jules Verne</customerName>
        <orderItems>
            <orderItem>
                <itemName>miniature steam machine</itemName>
                <quantity>2</quantity>
                <price>30 guineas</price>
                <comment>British import</comment>
            </orderItem>
            <orderItem>
                <itemName>map of Siberia</itemName>
                <quantity>1</quantity>
                <price>50 sous</price>
            </orderItem>
        </orderItems>
    </order>
    <order>
        <orderDate>01.06.1970</orderDate>
        <customerName>Arthur Clarke</customerName>
        <orderItems>
            <orderItem>
                <itemName>Meccano set "spaceship"</itemName>
                <quantity>1</quantity>
                <price>50 dollars</price>
            </orderItem>
        </orderItems>            
    </order>
</orders>
```

Comment: Are you modeling this data with regression?

Comment: @ndoogan I hope not. I have planned descriptive stuff mostly. But I don't know what ideas my supervisor might come up with, it may include research questions needing a regression model.

Answer (score 1):

If you're modeling this data with a regression analysis, you might consider a mixed effects (multilevel / hierarchical linear) model. In which case, or even in other cases of analysis in R, don't think about efficiency of storage. Create a data frame with a row for each of *k* items for each actor *i*. Thus, there will be a row for each order. Other fields in the row will capture covariates for the actor or for the order. Those representing characteristics of the actor will be repeated *k* times unless those characteristics change across orders. Such change is acceptable so long as you recognize it's change of the actor, not a characteristic of the item ordered (though the two could be related! So yes, it's a fuzzy distinction).

Example where actor 1 purchases 3 items A, B, and C and actor 2 purchases 1 item B. The age of actors and cost of items is included as well:

```
df <- data.frame( i=c(1,1,1,2), item=c("A","B","C","B"), itemCost=c(12,4,7,4), iage=c(23,23,23,47) )
df
#  i item itemCost iage
#1 1    A       12   23
#2 1    B        4   23
#3 1    C        7   23
#4 2    B        4   47
```

This kind of structure is pretty flexibly analyzed in R.

Comment: but this structure won't let me do descriptive statistics on the actor, e.g. a simple histogram of iage will show 3 at 23 and 1 at 47 instead of 1/1. Or do I have to import two separate dataframes, one for working with actors/orders only and one (in the joined format you suggest) for working with items and their relation to orders?

Comment: @rumtscho I might disagree. `mean(df$iage)` will give you a weighted mean age (weighted on purchases). This may be an important measure, or it may not. You can still obtain the unweighted mean by only considering unique values in the i column. But what if age changes across purchases? Consider that some person-level variables may change more frequently than age. The weighted case accounts for this. But you're right that it means something a little different. Consider what is most meaningful for your problem.

Comment: Consider the situation where one 23 year old purchases a quarter of your stock. And mostly 50 year-olds purchase the rest in realtively tiny quantities. Is it important to you to have the 23 year old big buyer fairly represented as such? Or as just another buyer? I can see it going either way, *depending* on your research question.

Comment: I will certainly have all three kinds of research questions: Ones about the buyers only, no matter what they bought, ones about the items only, no matter who bought them, and ones which need both information on items and buyers.